# How to get student's course to be selected from a list of Courses?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysqli

I am creating a script where I am able to edit student details. So what happens is that I select a student from a list of students in a drop down menu which is compiled with the code below:

```
   $studentInfo = array();

            while ($studentqrystmt->fetch()) {
                $studentHTML .= sprintf("<option value='%s'>%s</option>", $dbStudentId, $dbStudentUsername) . PHP_EOL;

                $studentData                    = array();
                $studentData["StudentId"]       = $dbStudentId;
                $studentData["StudentAlias"]    = $dbStudentalias;
                $studentData["StudentUsername"] = $dbStudentUsername;
                $studentData["CourseId"]        = $dbCourseId;
                $studentData["CourseNo"]        = $dbCourseNo;
                $studentData["CourseName"]      = $dbCourseName;

                array_push($studentInfo, $studentData);

            }


            $studentHTML .= '</select>';


            $studentForm = " 
            <form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . "' method='post' id='studentForm'> 
            <p>{$studentHTML}</p>   
            </form> 
            ";

            echo $studentForm;
```

Below is the source code of the list of students in the drop down menu:

```
<form action='...editstudent.php' method='post' id='studentForm'>
<p><strong>Students:</strong> <select name="student" id="studentsDrop">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='38'>u0495333 - Jack smith</option>
<option value='1'>u0867587 - Mayur Patel</option>
<option value='36'>u0867588 - paul smith</option>
<option value='39'>u4838229 - Chris Tucker</option>
</select> </p>   
<div id='targetdiv'></div> 
</form>
```

Now what happens is that when a user is selected, it displays all of the details of the student in a form in relevant text inputs:

```
$(document).ready( function(){

                    var studentinfo = [{"StudentId":38,"StudentAlias":"u0495333","StudentForename":"Jack","StudentSurname":"smith","StudentUsername":"u0495333","StudentEmail":"u0495333@hud.ac.uk","StudentDOB":"07-12-2012","StudentYear":2,"CourseId":19,"CourseNo":"BIO234","CourseName":"Biology"},
                    {"StudentId":36,"StudentAlias":"u0867588","StudentForename":"paul","StudentSurname":"smith","StudentUsername":"u0867588","StudentEmail":"u0867588@hud.ac.uk","StudentDOB":"05-12-2012","StudentYear":2,"CourseId":2,"CourseNo":"INFO102","CourseName":"Bsc Computing"}];

        $('#studentsDrop').change( function(){

            var studentId = $(this).val();

                    if (studentId !== '') {
        for (var i = 0, l = studentinfo.length; i < l; i++)
        {
                if (studentinfo[i].StudentId == studentId) { 

        var currentid = $('#currentStudentId').val(studentinfo[i].StudentId);
        var currentusername = $('#currentStudentUsername').val(studentinfo[i].StudentUsername);
        var currentcourse = $('#currentStudentCourse').val(studentinfo[i].CourseNo + " - " + studentinfo[i].CourseName);
        var newid = $('#newStudentId').val(studentinfo[i].StudentId);
        var newusername = $('#newStudentUsername').val(studentinfo[i].StudentUsername);
        var newcourse = $('#newStudentCourse').val(studentinfo[i].CourseId);

        var text = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        var split = text.split(' - ');
        $('#currentStudentAlias').val( split[0] );      
        $('#newStudentAlias').val( split[0] );     


                break;       
            }
          }  
        }
            else{
                $('#currentStudentAlias,#currentStudentUsername,#currentStudentCourse,#currentStudentId').val('');                   
                $('#newStudentAlias,#newStudentUsername,#newStudentCourse,#newStudentId').val('');                   

                }
        });

    });
```

Below is the form each data is suppose to be displayed in:

```
<form id='editForm'>

    <p><strong>Current Student Details</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='currentStudentId' name='StudentIdcurrent' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Student Number:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentStudentAlias' name='StudentAliascurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Username:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentStudentUsername' name='StudentUsernamecurrent' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <th>Course:</th>
    <td><input type='text' id='currentStudentCourse' name='StudentCoursecurrent' readonly='readonly' value=''/> </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <div id='currentAlert'></div>

    <p><strong>New Student Details</strong></p>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <td><input type='hidden' id='newStudentId' name='StudentIdNew' value='' /> </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th valign='top'>Student Number:</th>
    <td valign='top'><input type='text' id='newStudentAlias' name='StudentAliasNew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    <div id='studentAliasAlert'></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th valign='top'>Username:</th>
    <td valign='top'><input type='text' id='newStudentUsername' name='StudentUsernameNew' readonly='readonly' value='' /> </td>
    <div id='studentUsernameAlert'></div>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <th valign='top'>Course:</th>
    <td id='datacourse' valign='top'><select name="courses" id="newStudentCourse">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='1'>INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology</option>
<option value='2'>INFO102 - Bsc Computing</option>
<option value='8'>INFO103 - Business and Finance</option>
<option value='7'>INFO104 - English</option>
<option value='9'>INFO107 - Mathematics and Stats</option>
<option value='16'>INFO120 - Science</option>
</select>
    <div id='studentCourseAlert'></div></td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

Note you can see the list of courses displayed in the form above.

Now everything works in the jquery expect for this line: `var newcourse = $('#newStudentCourse').val(studentinfo[i].CourseId);`

What I am trying to do with the line above is that when a student is selected,, it will select the course the user is currently studying in the course drop down menu below out of the list of courses. The problem is that it still keeps displaying the "Please Select" option in the Course drop down menu after selecting a student

My question is that out of the list of courses in the drop down menu below, how can I get the student's course to be selected in the course drop down menu after a student is selected?

Comment: most of your php code is irrelevant to the issue. No need to post sql queries for client side problems. Post live html examples, not a bunch of loops to create options. `studentinfo` is not defined in your script. SInce this is area causing problem would help to see where it comes from

Comment: It looks like you mixing up how php and javascript/jQuery work. You are trying to access a php array `$studentInfo[$i]` via a javascript array `studentinfo[$i]` after the page has been loaded. Once the page has loaded, the php array is no longer accessible. You will need to either use Ajax/jQuery to get the php array again to set the value, or save the php array somewhere in your html code to be able to access it with javascript/jQuery.

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated code to include some of the missing vital code I accidentally missed out

Comment: again..if problem is client side, why are you posting server code and not live source?

Comment: @charlietfl I will post the live source as well but I will include it in an update

Comment: and the part you are having problems with is the code you should present... browser could care less about how you interact with DB or php functions to generate markup. All it sees is html and javascript. So far no html is posted and we have no idea what the php json_encode is echo'ing out

Comment: @Manixman Are you trying to reload the courses select box dynamically from the database when the user chooses a student or are you trying to get a pre-existing course from the select list?

Comment: @charlietfl I have updated code in my question, is it a lot better?

Comment: @GrayB The course drop down menu will just display the list of courses straightaway in the drop down menu, when a student is selected then from the list it will select the course the student is currently taking

Comment: code works fine....if the course value exists. Try Paul Smith...course value exists in options but Jack snith doesn't   http://jsfiddle.net/92NvR/

Comment: what a waste of time going to the car factory to find out how the wheels are made for my car that won't start... when problem was a dead battery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jQuery command to update the value of the courses select box

```
$('#newStudentCourse').val(newcourse);
```

I attached a simplified version of the jQuery command: http://jsfiddle.net/waQYz/

Comment: Can I ask you quick question, after the user has selected a new course for the student, how can I get the current course text input to display the course number and course name of the new course selected as that at the moment it is displaying the course's id the value of option selected from the course drop down menu) in that text input after the change?

Comment: In the last block of code in my questio if yo scroll down, you will see what the course drop down menu looks like, you will be able to see the course's id (value of drop down option), course number and course name

Comment: @Manixman I change the answer to use your Id instead. Also I update the jsfiddle to explain how to update a input text field. http://jsfiddle.net/waQYz/1/

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing directly wrong with your code, if your posted edit is your exact code. I copied it into a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GSDUx/ - and it is working as designed.

Your problem is that you have 4 students in your `student` `<select>`, but only 2 students in your  `studentinfo` array, and only 1 of the courses in the `studentinfo` array is also in the  `course` `<select>`.

So the only time it will change the `course` `<select>` is for
`<option value='36'>u0867588 - paul smith</option>`
=> `<option value='2'>INFO102 - Bsc Computing</option>`
**OR**
`<option value='38'>u0495333 - Jack smith</option>`
= > `<option value="">Please Select</option>`
(this changes to `<option value="">Please Select</option>` because `CourseId:19` does not exist.

```
<select name="student">
<option value='38'>u0495333 - Jack smith</option>
<option value='1'>u0867587 - Mayur Patel</option>
<option value='36'>u0867588 - paul smith</option>
<option value='39'>u4838229 - Chris Tucker</option>
```

---

```
var studentinfo =
[{"StudentId":38,"StudentAlias":"u0495333","StudentForename":"Jack","StudentSurname":"smith","StudentUsername":"u0495333","StudentEmail":"u0495333@hud.ac.uk","StudentDOB":"07-12-2012","StudentYear":2,"CourseId":19,"CourseNo":"BIO234","CourseName":"Biology"},  
{"StudentId":36,"StudentAlias":"u0867588","StudentForename":"paul","StudentSurname":"smith","StudentUsername":"u0867588","StudentEmail":"u0867588@hud.ac.uk","StudentDOB":"05-12-2012","StudentYear":2,"CourseId":2,"CourseNo":"INFO102","CourseName":"Bsc Computing"}];
```

---

```
<select name="courses">
<option value="">Please Select</option>
<option value='1'>INFO101 - Bsc Information Communication Technology</option>
<option value='2'>INFO102 - Bsc Computing</option>
<option value='8'>INFO103 - Business and Finance</option>
<option value='7'>INFO104 - English</option>
<option value='9'>INFO107 - Mathematics and Stats</option>
<option value='16'>INFO120 - Science</option>
```